# Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings

Tags: php

Me sale este error:

> Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in C:\xampp\htdocs\prueba\modulos\footer.php

He añadido la linea `date.timezone=Europe/Madrid` en el archivo php.ini. He reiniciado el apache pero nada. Estoy usando el xampp en windows 7 y la version php es la siguiente 5.6.24

En el archivo que hago la llamada simplemente uso esta funcion:

```
echo date("Y");
```

Comment: Buenas. Al final volvía a reinstalar XAMPP y parece que funciona bien. Muchas gracias por las respuestas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de tu llamada a la funcion `date()` coloca: `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`

`'America/Los_Angeles'` cambialo por tu zona horaria en base a lista ofrecida en la documentación oficial de php http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.php